# Returning fetched JSON correctly but can't get it into Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, json, rest, chart.js, fetch

I'm a few months into learning web dev and trying to escape lesson purgatory by doing some of my own projects. The first is intended to be a chrome extension that populates a new tab with content. In this case, I want that content to be some crypto price charts, news articles, and tweets. This question is about the charts.

I have a codepen set up here with all the code for this question: https://codepen.io/diggitydoge/pen/QWWGMNb

**The Problem**
I can see the data I want (one price array and one time array) in the console with the following, but don't know how to get it into my chart and can't find any guide or answer here that clearly explains how I would:

```js
const btcTime = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
    const json = await response.json();
    const data = json.Data.Data
    const times = data.map(obj => obj.time)
    return times;
}

const btcPrice = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
    const json = await response.json();
    const data = json.Data.Data
    const price = data.map(obj => obj.high)
    return {
      price
    }
}

async function btcTimeArray(){
  let results = await btcTime()
  
  console.log(results)
}

btcTimeArray() 

async function btcPriceArray(){
  let results = await btcPrice()
  
  console.log(results)
}

btcPriceArray() 


//---HELPER FUNCTIONS---//
  function checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
  }
```

I have btcTime returning an array and btcPrice returning an object containing an array just to see if either way makes a difference in this next step:

**Inserting the results into Chart.JS datasets**

Here's what the datasets look like with dummy data that works

```js
labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Population',
            data: [
               610994,
               181045,
               153060,
               106519,
               105162,
               95072 
            ],
```

So at this point, I...

1. see my Bitcoin price and time data in the console
2. need to know how to store/call/target/whatever it to place the times into the Chart.JS labels property, and the prices into the Chart.js data key in the datasets object.

I tried something like this but it didn't seem to work:

```js
labels: btcTime,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Population',
            data: btcPrice,
```

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @headhunterkev!

I actually figured it out myself but I'll have to check your way out!

Here's how I did it: https://codepen.io/diggitydoge/pen/MWWmgJp

```js
///  Calling API and modeling data for each chart ///
const btcData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
  const json = await response.json();
  const data = json.Data.Data
  const times = data.map(obj => obj.time)
  const prices = data.map(obj => obj.high)
  return {
    times,
    prices
  }
}


const cosmosData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=ATOM&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
  const json = await response.json();
  const data = json.Data.Data
  const times = data.map(obj => obj.time)
  const prices = data.map(obj => obj.high)
  return {
    times,
    prices
  }
}


const ethereumData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=ETH&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
  const json = await response.json();
  const data = json.Data.Data
  const times = data.map(obj => obj.time)
  const prices = data.map(obj => obj.high)
  return {
    times,
    prices
  }
}


const checker = async () => {
  //enter API URL into fetch to see data in console
  const response = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=119&api_key=0646cc7b8a4d4b54926c74e0b20253b57fd4ee406df79b3d57d5439874960146');
  const json = await response.json();
  const data = json.Data.Data
  return {
   data
  }
}


/// console.log functions to check data ///
async function btcDataCheck() {
  let results = await btcData()

  console.log(results)
}
btcDataCheck()

async function checkerFunction() {
  let results = await checker()

  console.log(results)
}
checkerFunction()

/// Error handling ///
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
  }
}



/// Charts ///
let createBtcChart
let createCosmosChart
let createethereumChart

async function printBtcChart() {
  let { times, prices } = await btcData()

  let btcChart = document.getElementById('btcChart').getContext('2d');

  let gradient = btcChart.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);

  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(247,147,26,.5)');
  gradient.addColorStop(.425, 'rgba(255,193,119,0)');

  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Red Hat Text';
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;

  createBtcChart = new Chart(btcChart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: times,
      datasets: [{
        label: '$',
        data: prices,
        backgroundColor: gradient,
        borderColor: 'rgba(247,147,26,1)',
        borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        borderCapStyle: 'round',
        borderWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        lineTension: .2,
      }]
    },

    options: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'Heckin Chart!',
        fontSize: 35
      },

      legend: {
        display: false
      },

      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }
      },

      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }]
      },

      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          //This removes the tooltip title
          title: function() {}
       },
        //this removes legend color
        displayColors: false,
        yPadding: 10,
        xPadding: 10,
        position: 'nearest',
        caretSize: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
        bodyFontSize: 15,
        bodyFontColor: '#303030' 
      }
    }
  });
}



async function printCosmosChart() {
  let { times, prices } = await cosmosData()

  let cosmosChart = document.getElementById('cosmosChart').getContext('2d');

  let gradient = cosmosChart.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);

  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(27,30,54,.5)');
  gradient.addColorStop(.425, 'rgba(46,49,72,0)');

  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Red Hat Text';
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;

  createCosmosChart = new Chart(cosmosChart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: times,
      datasets: [{
        label: "",
        data: prices,
        backgroundColor: gradient,
        borderColor: 'rgba(46,49,72,1)',
        borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        borderCapStyle: 'round',
        borderWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        lineTension: .2,
      }]
    },

    options: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'Heckin Chart!',
        fontSize: 35
      },

      legend: {
        display: false
      },

      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }
      },

      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }]
      },

      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          //This removes the tooltip title
          title: function() {}
       },
        //this removes legend color
        displayColors: false,
        yPadding: 10,
        xPadding: 10,
        position: 'nearest',
        caretSize: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
        bodyFontSize: 15,
        bodyFontColor: '#303030' 
      }
    }
  });
}


async function printEthereumChart() {
  let { times, prices } = await ethereumData()

  let ethereumChart = document.getElementById('ethereumChart').getContext('2d');

  let gradient = ethereumChart.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);

  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(78,56,216,.5)');
  gradient.addColorStop(.425, 'rgba(118,106,192,0)');

  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Red Hat Text';
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;

  createEthereumChart = new Chart(ethereumChart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: times,
      datasets: [{
        label: '$',
        data: prices,
        backgroundColor: gradient,
        borderColor: 'rgba(118,106,192,1)',
        borderJoinStyle: 'round',
        borderCapStyle: 'round',
        borderWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        lineTension: .2,
      }]
    },

    options: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'Heckin Chart!',
        fontSize: 35
      },

      legend: {
        display: false
      },

      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }
      },

      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {}
        }]
      },

      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          //This removes the tooltip title
          title: function() {}
       },
        //this removes legend color
        displayColors: false,
        yPadding: 10,
        xPadding: 10,
        position: 'nearest',
        caretSize: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
        bodyFontSize: 15,
        bodyFontColor: '#303030' 
      }
    }
  });
}

async function updateEthereumPrice() {
  let { times, prices } = await ethereumData()
  let currentPrice = prices[prices.length-1].toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("ethPrice").innerHTML = "$" + currentPrice;
}

async function updateCosmosPrice() {
  let { times, prices } = await cosmosData()
  let currentPrice = prices[prices.length-1].toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("atomPrice").innerHTML = "$" + currentPrice;
}

async function updateBitcoinPrice() {
  let { times, prices } = await btcData()
  let currentPrice = prices[prices.length-1].toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("btcPrice").innerHTML = "$" + currentPrice;
}

updateEthereumPrice()
updateCosmosPrice()
updateBitcoinPrice()

printBtcChart()
printCosmosChart()
printEthereumChart()
```

```css
$card-text-color: #303030;

///  FONTS  ///
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

h1, 
h2, 
p {
    font-family: 'Red Hat Text', sans-serif;
    color: $card-text-color;
}

/// Card Container ///
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


/// Cards ///
cards {
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.btc,
.cosmos,
.ethereum {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 250px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, 60px) 1fr;
    grid-template: 
        "info"
        "chart";
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.btc {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px rgba(247,147,26,.15);
}

.cosmos {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px rgba(46,49,72,.15);
}

.ethereum {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px rgba(78,56,216,.15);
}

.asset-info {
    grid-area: info;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.title {
    display: inline-flex;
}

card h1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

// .asset-price {

// }


/// Charts ///
#btcChart,
#cosmosChart,
#ethereumChart {
    grid-area: chart;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Red+Hat+Text:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Issa Chart!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <container class="container">
    <cards class="cards">
        <bitcoin style="width: 30%" class="btc">
            <card class="asset-info">
                <div class="title">
                    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg" width="15%"> 
                    <h1>Bitcoin</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <h2 class="asset-price" id="btcPrice"></h2>
                </div>
            </card>
            <canvas id="btcChart"></canvas>
        </bitcoin>

        <cosmos style="width: 30%" class="cosmos">
            <card class="asset-info">
                <div class="title">
                    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/atm.svg" width="15%"> 
                    <h1>Cosmos</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <h2 class="asset-price" id="atomPrice"></h2>
                </div>
            </card>
            <canvas id="cosmosChart"></canvas>
        </cosmos>

        <ethereum style="width: 30%" class="ethereum">
            <card class="asset-info">
                <div class="title">
                    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/eth.svg" width="10%"> 
                    <h1>Ethereum</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <h2 class="asset-price" id="ethPrice"></h2>
                </div>
            </card>
            <canvas id="ethereumChart"></canvas>
        </ethereum>
    </cards>
  </container>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not really into the async-await-stuff. Maybe my code relating this issue is horrible. Please feel free to correct me.

You have to wait for the fetch-request and its data to create your chart or you have to update it when your data arrives. I used the updating method.
[I put my code in a JSBin.](https://jsbin.com/kefamugazi/2/edit?js,output)

```
async function btcTimeArray() {
  let results = await btcTime()

  console.log(results)
  updateTime(results)
}

function updateTime(results) {
  btcChart.data.labels = results
  btcChart.update()
}
```

P.S.: You should compare my code to yours. I made a few changes I think are better, but this can be a personal opinion. It was only for my time working with your code, it may not what you want. I use this site for displaying code differences: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

P.P.S: I would add a colored vertical line at your currently hovered index instead of using a big point for the data that's hovered and you're displaying the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check your way out!

Took me a while but I figured it out and included my answer below.